# argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable for django string " "

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, django-queryset

I am trying to split my query based on a space `" "`. example `first_name` `last_name` however if I try to check for spaces in my seach I get the error

> argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

```
if ' ' in query: #This is where is the error is generated
```

Trying to fix the above issue. Below is the entire code

```
class QList(SelectRelatedMixin, ListView):
    model = Question

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(QList, self).get_queryset().order_by('-created_at')
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')

        if ' ' in query:
            query = query.split()
            queryset = queryset.filter(
                chain(User.objects.filter(first_name__icontains=query[0], last_name__icontains=query[1]),
                      User.objects.filter(first_name__icontains=query[1], last_name__icontains=query[0])))

            return queryset
        else:
            queryset = queryset.filter(
                Q(user__username__iexact=query) |
                Q(user__first_name__iexact=query) |
                Q(user__last_name__iexact=query)

                )
        return queryset
```

Can anyone suggest a workaround

Comment: What you want to check. Is `query` is empty in `if ' ' in query`?

Comment: @ShafikurRahman Just want to separate `first_name` `" "` `last_name`. So if there is a `space` or `" "` between 2 words. The 1st word becomes the 1st name and the 2nd word becomes the last name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To split string just say your name is "Marco Bianchi".

```
query = "Marco Bianchi"
first_name = query.split(" ")[0]
last_name = query.split(" ")[1]
```

Update:
Instead of

```
if ' ' in query:
     query = query.split()
```

Use this

```
query = query.split(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use split string like :

```
class QList(SelectRelatedMixin, ListView):
model = Question

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super(QList, self).get_queryset().order_by('-created_at')
    query = self.request.GET.get('q')

    query = query.split()

    if len(query) == 2:
        queryset = queryset.filter(
        chain(User.objects.filter(first_name__icontains=query[0], last_name__icontains=query[1]),
              User.objects.filter(first_name__icontains=query[1], last_name__icontains=query[0])))
    else:
        queryset = queryset.filter(
            Q(user__username__iexact=query) |
            Q(user__first_name__iexact=query) |
            Q(user__last_name__iexact=query)

            )

    return queryset
```